# Regular expression to validate the given input which accepts one space or Hyphen which is part of the text length

Tags: regex

In the below example, I am validating the 4 characters' text with include either one space or Hyphen (-) or without that also only 4 characters.

```
Regex : ^[A-Z0-9]{4}$|(?=^.{4}$)^[A-Z0-9]+[- ]?[A-Z0-9]+$
```

It worked the cases as below cases but it failed to validate the text contains all same characters like 1111, AAAA is not allowed

```
1234  valid
12-4  valid
12 4  valid  
1111  invalid ( as all are the same characters)
11-1  invalid ( as all are the same characters)
12345 invalid
```

Comment: Is `1 -2` valid?

Comment: No only one space or Hypen. and space or Hyphen is in between character not start or end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to match your strings:

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9]+[ -]?[A-Z0-9]+$)(?!([A-Z0-9])(?:\1|[ -]){3}).{4}$
```

Regex explanation:

- `^` start of string
- `(?=[A-Z0-9]+[ -]?[A-Z0-9]+)` asserts that the string consists of one or more of `A-Z0-9`, an optional   or `-`, and one or more of `A-Z0-9`
- `(?!([A-Z0-9])(?:\1|[ -]){3})` asserts that the first character is not repeated in every position where there is a character
- `.{4}$` matches only 4 characters between start and end of string

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iU04b9/3)

Comment: Thanks @Nick its working in most of the cases but one of the case its failing, the case is it has minimum and maximum length like below it can be minimum 5 maximum 10
```^(?=[A-Z0-9]+[ -]?[A-Z0-9]+)(?!([A-Z0-9])(?:\1|[ -]){4,9}).{5,10}$ ```
working as expected other than same digitis 
like 11114 allowed but 11111116 not allowed because the 1's are more than 4 
can you please correct the my regex for this case.

Comment: @HarinathaReddy I thought it was supposed to be only 4 characters? The question even says that `12345` is invalid...

Comment: Yes, @Nick your right, along with that I have min and max logic, I thought a similar one will work but it's giving issue with the same values case.

Comment: You could try `^(?=[A-Z0-9]+[ -]?[A-Z0-9]+)(?!([A-Z0-9])(.*\1){4}).{5,10}$` https://regex101.com/r/1FCB9Z/1

Comment: as per requirement 1111116 this is valid because its more than 5 characters (min 5)but it's not allowed with the regex because more than 4 1's are there

Comment: @HarinathaReddy and that regex I gave you does not match `1111116`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248373/discussion-between-harinatha-reddy-and-nick).

Comment: Hi @Nick the regex is not working in a few cases like below 
https://regex101.com/r/PImakS/1
those cases are not valid buts its validating

Comment: ^(?=.{4}$)([0-9])(?!(?:[ -]?\1)+$)[0-9]*[ -]?[0-9]+$ this is working for most of the cases

Comment: @HarinathaReddy sorry there was a small error in the regex (missing end-of-line anchor), it should have been `^(?=[0-9]+[ -]?[0-9]+$)(?!([0-9])(?:\\1|[ -]){3}).{4}$` https://regex101.com/r/PImakS/2